# How to remove Redis keys efficiently on the fly

Tags: redis, key

I have a Redis 2.8.3 service where I am storing data in sets (created with SADD) such as:

```
Customers (set) 
.....Custname (set)
.........application (set)
..............time (set)
...................detail (hash)
```

Once each detail hash has been processed, it is removed using SREM and then if the parent set (time and application) is found empty using SCARD, it is removed using SREM.

Although this is working, it appears to be leaving the keys for each removed item. So there
are keys such as 'Customer:Custname:application:time' left lying around.

What is the most efficient way to remove the set members and remove the corresponding key at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with `LUA` procedure would be best choise. The pseudocode looks like

```
if 1 == srem(key, value) then 
    if 0 == scard(key) then 
       del(key)
    end if 
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @misterion. I have implemented this.